# How to implement the "dolce" marking?

Tags: classical-guitar, expression

In Italian, *dolce* means "sweet", which doesn't help much. How am I supposed to play it on classical guitar? Some people mentioned "softly", which may be good, but there surely is more to it than that.

I am interested generally, but also specifically in this one measure, taken from Norbert Leclercq's *Noir*.

[image: measure13]

Comment: Closer to the soundhole. More legato. More vibrato. Softer. More *espressivo.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where along the string you pluck will vary the *tone*. Pluck close to the bridge, and there's more treble, nasal sound. So further away from that point will produce a more dolce sound. Perhaps even as far as over the sound hole.

Also, *what* produces the sound will be variable. Use only the very fleshy part of the fingers, and brush, rather than twang(!) the strings. No nails used. A combination of both will give as much dolce as possible.